# IN function does not work with decimals

Tags: sas

This code gives the error "Expecting an integer constant" . Why? It is pretty straight forward and I couldn't find anything saying in() does not work with decimals. Do I need a "do" somewhere? Thanks.

```
  data clustered;
  set combd;

 if (avpm in(393821:450041) or avpm in(337601:393821) or avpm in     
  (225161:281381)) and fsp in (.8768:1) then class='1';

 if (avpm in(112720:168940) or avpm in(56500:112720) or avpm in 
  (280.06:56500)) and fsp in (.8768:1) then class='2';

 if avpm in(280.06:56500) and (fsp in (.507:.6303) or fsp in (.3838:.507) 
  or fsp in (.2606:.3838)) then class='3';

 if avpm in(280.06:56500) and (fsp in (.1373:.2606) or fsp in   
  (.0141:.1373)) then class='4';

 if avpm in(280.06:56500) and fsp in (.8768:1) then class='5';

 if avpm in(280.06:56500) and (fsp in (.8768:1) or fsp in (.7535:.8768) or 
  fsp in (.6303:.7535)) then class='6';

run;
```

Answer (score 1):

`IN` does not work with decimals.

In fact, `IN` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

`IN()` is an operator that does the following, according to the SAS [documentation on operators](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000780367.htm):

> equal to one of a list

Note `list`.  That is, it is not saying that a number is between the start and the end; rather, it is expanding the start to end as a list of integers and evaluating whether it is in that list.  You can see further down that page in [The IN operator in numeric comparisons](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/a000780367.htm#a002636271):

> You can use a shorthand notation to specify a range of sequential integers to search. The range is specified by using the syntax M:N as a value in the list to search, where M is the lower bound and N is the upper bound. M and N must be integers, and M, N, and all the integers between M and N are included in the range.

Importantly, any number that is not an integer is by definition not included in this range.  So:

```
3.5 in (2:4)
```

is false, as 3.5 is not in the list `(2,3,4)`.

```
data test;
  x = 3.5;
  y = x in (2:4);
  put x= y=;
  stop;
run;

x=3.5 y=0
```

You need to use `ge` and/or `le` (or `gt` and/or `lt`) to do what you want.

```
0.8768 le fsp le 1
```

You can chain them together like that, so it still is relatively easy to write.

Comment: Thanks Joe; makes sense.

Comment: The in operator works with lists of decimal numbers if they are specified discretely, for example `if x in (0, 0.5, 1)` will be true if x equals 0.5.  You can't really expect SAS to match against an uncountably infinite set of numbers though.